# How do I take values from a graph and use them for a tkinter animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, animation

I am currently trying to create a water tank with tkinter, having the water level function as an animation based on the y-values of a graph. How can I extract the values from the graph and have a functioning animation? Below is code based on time, how can I take values from the graph and implement it? Haven't been able to get far.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import time
import numpy as np

def plot_graph():
    # Get the slider values
    start = x_start_slider.get()
    end = x_end_slider.get()
    step = step_slider.get()

# Generate x and y values for the graph
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# Create a new figure and plot the graph
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)

# Create a canvas and display the graph on it
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graph_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

# Start animating the water level
animate_water_level()

def animate_water_level():
    current_time = time.time() - start_time
    water_level = (current_time % animation_duration) / animation_duration  # Adjust the water level based on time
water_height = (300 - 50) * (1 - water_level) + 50

# Clear the previous water level rectangle
canvas.delete("water_level")

# Draw the new water level rectangle
canvas.create_rectangle(20, water_height, 180, 300, fill="blue", tags="water_level")

# Schedule the next update
window.after(100, animate_water_level)

# Create a window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Graphing App")

# Create frames for tank model and graph
tank_frame = tk.Frame(window)
tank_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

graph_frame = tk.Frame(window)
graph_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create tank model widgets
canvas = tk.Canvas(tank_frame, width=200, height=300)
canvas.pack()
```

Comment: You already have the values: `y` (result of `np.sin(x)`).